# Can't retract Very Low Quality flag on question

Tags: bug, flags, low-quality-posts, retracted-flags

Earlier today, I cast a Very Low Quality flag on [this now deleted question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/77363/15950). While it was still pending

[image]

I couldn't retract the flag; instead of a Retract Flag button, a disabled Flag Question button was shown:

[image]

I suspect this has something to do with the question not qualifying for a Very Low Quality flag anymore due to it already being in a review queue.