# It's (sometimes) possible to cast another flag on a question you have a pending VLQ flag on

Tags: bug, status-review, flags, low-quality-posts

I flagged [this now-deleted Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/401806/79696) as Very Low Quality. When I looked at it an hour later, I noticed that the VLQ flagging option was gone (presumably because [it was in a review queue at that moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315421/295232)), but I *could* add another flag (as off-topic, though it would probably work with spam flags as well, and this particular question might qualify as such since it's essentially a job offer).

This resulted in a rather strange situation where I had two pending flags on the question:

[image]

I'm marking this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) since under normal circumstances, the system prevents adding a flag while another one is still pending, whether this is via the site itself or the API.

Comment: Is this a dupe?, does this answer your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258187/282094 - When you VLQ and someone agrees it enters the close queue, you can't VLQ again but you can put another flag on it.

Comment: It's highly related (and I read it while doing research) - this is probably just another symptom of the same root cause. But this bug might be easier to solve, I don't know ...

Answer (score 3):

This was tested and no longer appears to be an issue. I've updated the status to completed.

Comment: [It's still happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l86Yc.png) - that's on GameDev.SE.

Comment: @Glorfindel aside from the screen shot you have linked to do you have more details around the problem you can point us to? That would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a frequent user of keyboard shortcuts - M F 5 Enter, M F 3 3 Enter

Comment: @Glorfindel With regard to keyboard shortcuts, there's [this other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357805/3k-users-can-raise-two-flags-on-the-same-question-using-keyboard-shortcuts) reporting that. Is that a duplicate of this?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog maybe. I'm not sure about the exact situation that led to this question; that might as well have been resolved.