# <3k users can raise two flags on the same question using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: bug, status-review, flags, keyboard-shortcuts

Normally, you can only flag a post once: once you've raised, say, a spam flag on a question, the system will prevent you from casting a recommend closure flag using the mouse.

On one site, I raised a red flag on a post, and then, because George was curious, used the keyboard shortcuts to try and raise a "Not suitable for this site" flag:

> [image]

<sub>Editor's note: the screenshot has been replaced with one that shows the two flags pending at once, while the one previously provided showed them after the author had already retracted them.</sub>

And it actually went through.  I have 101 reputation there and therefore don't have close-vote privileges, which is the equal of a "Not suitable" flag.  Can we please fix this, since the system ordinarily prevents users from having these two flags pending at the same time for the same post?

The question I reproduced this on is [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298785/how-do-i-create-facets-with-price-ranges), in case a moderator wants to investigate more.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a site where you have less than 3,000 reputation, and make sure keyboard shortcuts are enabled in your profile settings.
2. Flag a random question (or even better, a spam or R/A post)  as spam, rude/abusive, or "very low quality" (if that option exists for that question), using either the mouse or through keyboard shortcuts (doesn't matter for this step).
3. Open the flag dialog with the mouse. Notice that the options to flag as "needs improvement" or "a duplicate..." (i.e. the recommend closure flag options) are grayed out and unselectable with the mouse. Close the flag dialog.
4. Press the following key sequence: <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Notice how the system allowed you to flag the question as "Needs detail or clarity" with the keyboard, *even though* this option was prevented when using the mouse.
5. Retract the two flags. (Note that you must click the button twice to retract both flags.)

I have a theory that this might be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), or just an "OK hack", because it's the >3K equivalent of voting to close a question and red-flagging it.  Is this the case, or should this still be prevented?

Comment: I just noticed this again. Currently, when off-topic questions show up on MSE, I press `M` `F` `3` (small pause to allow the flag dialog to load) `2` `1` `V` `D` `G` `O` as quickly as I can. The final `G` `O` to go to the owner’s profile is to check whether they’ve posted their question elsewhere previously. Shortly before the redirection, however, my eyes catch a red notification saying “An error occured \[…\]”. Going back to check if the vote and flag went through, it seems to have worked, but it’s surprising I can access the _disabled_ flag option using shortcuts when checking the flag!

Comment: I'd say it's illegitimate. It essentially allows <3k users to game the system to get two helpful flags on every spam question, which is unfair to other users, especially 3k+ users who can't.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yeah, and those flags would count toward extra badges.  Fair point.